# NX - Sharing buildable libs won't build

Tags: angular, webpack, nrwl-nx, nrwl, webpack-module-federation

### Current Behavior

I added a library with the `--buildable` flag and then shared it with two apps using `sharedMappings` in the `webpack.config.js` files. Then I added a service which is being used in the aforementioned apps.

App `dashboard` sets a variable in the created service, then after clicking on the `Login` button, the `login` app logs the variable's value.

Serving the application works fine. Unfortunately, building the application fails (see Failure Logs) using the following command:
`nx run-many --target=build --all`

### Expected Behavior

That it builds fine.
Strangely enough, doing this without the `--buildable` flag, it does works fine.

### Steps to Reproduce

I forked the following repo: https://github.com/Coly010/ng-mfe-example and did what has been described in the Current Behavior: https://github.com/TomONeill/ng-mfe-example/commit/f62aeb9702ee7fa97dd85948991253a8ba1c713c

#### Failure Logs

```
./libs/awesomelib/libname/src/index.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: C:\Workspace\nx\ng-mfe-example\libs\awesomelib\libname\src\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at C:\Workspace\nx\ng-mfe-example\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:59:26
```

Edit:
The nx team is going to resolve this issue:
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/6923#issuecomment-933608882